# JTable display char[]

Tags: java, swing, jtable, char

I have some problems displaying data in JTable. My app is using a JTable and a custom AbstractTableModel. In my AbstractTableModel I have a private field `SomeClass[] array` and that class is something like:

```
public char[] field1;
public char[] field2;
etc.
```

Also in my AbstractTableModel I have override `getValueAt` method and it contains something like this:

```
...
switch(column){
case(0):
retrun array[row].field1;
case(1):
return array[row].field2;
}
etc.
```

When I do a `System.out.println(array[row].field1)` the data is displayed correctly, but in my jTable is something like "[C@203 .........".

What is the problem? :-s How can i fix this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default renderer for a JTable simply invokes the toString() method on the Object that is returned from the getValueAt(...) method.

field1 is a char array. The toString() representation of the array is the wierd text that you see.

You should not be storing a char array in the model to represent the data of a cell. Instead create and store an actual String in the model.

Comment: I'm working with large data sets (around 100k) and I need some memory space. That's why I had chosen char[] instead of String. Isn't any way to display char[] in jTable? :-s

Comment: Yes you can, but you'd have to create your own cell renderer to do this. Not too hard to do though.

Comment: And if I create a cell renderer, it will be difficult to implement a "Quick Search" box that will update table when a key is pressed? :-s  Again... I'm talking about memory space ....

Comment: @IonutUngureanu: On further thought, I urge you not to have your table model hold such an enormous amount of data. Why not instead have it held by the database, and only extract what you need to display when you need to display it.

Comment: The renderer would need to convert the char[] to a String before display the data. I'm not sure what a "Quick Search" feature is. Mabe you are talking about "filtering" the model to display rows that contain certain characters. A JTable supports filtering by default but the filtering works by using a Regex to find the matching data. Since a Regex works on a String, I'm not sure how a model containing char[] will work. Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for a filtering example.